# Codeigniter File Upload - IIS 7.5 HTTP Error 500.0

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis

I seem to be having a problem with file upload in `CodeIgniter` resulting in the error within the title. I have the file upload working on the same server on a different website, which is why I thought the same code would work for this upload. The problem occurs the second I try to `upload`.

Here is the code I am currently using within my `controller`

```
public function bulk_product_upload_file()
{
    $location_of_bulk_product_files = LOCATION OF FOLDER;
    if ($this->is_post()):
        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])):
            $date_for_file = date("dmyHis");

            $config['upload_path'] = $location_of_bulk_product_files; //upload directory
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'xlsx'; // allowed file types
            $config['max_size'] = '100';
            $config['overwrite']  = TRUE;
            $config['remove_space']  = TRUE;
            $config['file_name'] = $date_for_file;
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if($this->upload->do_upload()):
            // I have also tried if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile')): that resulted in the same error
                // file upload success
            else:
               // file upload failed
            endif;
        else:
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message_error','Please select a file to upload.');
            redirect('main/create_bulk_product');
        endif;
    else:
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message_error','Sorry! Somthing went wrong, please try again.');
        redirect('main/create_bulk_product');
    endif;
}
```

And the `error` I am receiving:

`HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
Module  FastCgiModule
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler PHP
Error Code  0x00000000`

I'm more baffled that it is working on another website on the same server but not this one. All the settings seem to be exactly the same too. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your code looks good ... you can test this issue by adding break point step by step ...

Comment: also post your .log file . you can found error there

Comment: @chhameed How would I do this (Adding break points)? I think it could be something to do with my Codeigniter version as the new website is using a newer version.

Comment: what is your log file said ?

Comment: Turns out there was a problem with the upload library with the version of CodeIgniter I was using. Problem fixed by using the new upload.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with CodeIgniter itself. 3.1.2 had a problem with the upload library.